# Union of elements in quotient group

Tags: group-theory

For a quotient group G/H, is is true that union of all elements in G/H equals G?

I think it is true because union of all cosets relative to H covers G. But when I asked this question to two of my professors, both of them said it is not so true because we should view each thing in G/H as a single element of G/H, not a set. But I think being a set does not prevent them from being an element of G/H? Or is there some convention behind?

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confused. If $N\trianglelefteq G$ then $G/N$ is a group of **the left cosets of $N$** with the operation being multiplication of cosets. It means that the elements of $G/N$ are the cosets themselves (as sets), not the elements which are inside the cosets. So it's not true to say that the union of the elements of $G/N$ give the group $G$ because the elements of $G/N$ are not elements of $G$ at all. For example, $\langle 2 \rangle\trianglelefteq\mathbb{Z_4}$. Then:

$\mathbb{Z_4}/\langle 2\rangle=\{\langle 2\rangle, 1+\langle 2\rangle\}$.

But are $\langle 2\rangle$ and $1+\langle 2\rangle$ elements of $\mathbb{Z_4}$? No, they aren't. The elements which are **inside** these cosets are elements of $\mathbb{Z_4}$, not the cosets themselves.

Comment: Yes I understand the element of quotient group G/H is coset and is not element of G and that’s why I used union. So I’m not saying that <2> and 1+<2> are elements of Z_4, I meant they are subsets of Z_4 and what I claimed is (1 + <2>) UNION <2> = Z_4. Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be. But it's wrong to call that "union of elements of $G/H$". It should be "union of the elements of $G$ which are inside the elements of $G/H$".

Comment: Sorry I don’t quite understand your comment. For example G = Z, and H = 3Z = {3n | n in Z}, then G/H = {<0>, <1>, <2>}, where <i> = {3n + i | n in Z}, i = 0, 1 or 2. We know union of <i> (i = 0, 1, 2) is G right? But each <i> is an element of G/H. Why it is wrong to say union of elements of G/H is G?

Answer (score 1):

You're right. By definition, $G/H$ is the set of equivalent classes of the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $g$ defined by: $$\forall g,g'\in G,g\sim g'\Leftrightarrow gg'^{-1}\in H.$$

Given any $g\in G$, the element $gH$ of $G/H$ is, still, the equivalence class of $g$ under $\sim$, hence a subset of $G$.

Since any element of $g$ is in $gH$, it does follow that $G=\bigcup G/H$, or in other words, $G=\bigcup_{g\in G}gH$.

Comment: That's right, but it just shouldn't be called the union of elements of $G/H$. It is the union of the elements which are inside the elements of $G/H$.

Comment: @Mark hi mark see my reply to your thread.

Comment: Hmm. I always thought of $A\cup B$ as "the union of $A$ and $B$". Hence, if $S=\{A,B\}$, I'd think of $A\cup B$ as "the union of the elements of $S$". Is it really said differently in usual texts?

Comment: @Scientifica, it is different. $\{2\}$ and $\{\{2\}\}$ are not the same set for example. One contains the element $2$ and the other contains a set which contains the element $2$. $2$ is not an element of the second set.

Comment: @Scientifica I agree with you. Is there another understanding of this statement that resulted in at least my professors and Mark comment my claim in exact the same way (and even use almost the same example....)

Comment: @Mark would it be correct to say the union of all elements in {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} is {1, 2, 3, 4}?

Comment: @Zhou Chenliang, from what I know (maybe some define it in different ways but it's strange for me to imagine that) it's not correct. The elements of the set you wrote are $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$. The numbers $1,2,3,4$ are not its elements.

Comment: @Mark yes the elements of that set is {1, 2} and {3, 4}, and the union of these should be {1,2,3,4} right?....

Comment: Anyway, I'm sorry if I confused you, it's not that important in group theory. (though in set theory it is very important to be formal in these things). My point is this: a set of sets is not the same thing as a set of the elements which are inside the inner sets.

Comment: @Mark Let's see some terminology [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)}(here). We do say "the union of two sets $A$ and $B$". So, if $S={A,B}$, the elements of $S$ are $A$ and $B$, and hence saying "the union of the elements of $S$" is the same as "the union of $A$ and $B$". There's also another terminology (see the "Arbitrary unions" section in the previous link. The union of a set is, basically, the union of all the elements of that set. So, according to that definition as well, the union of $\{A,B\}$ is $A\cup B$.

Comment: @ZhouChenliang I don't agree with Mark's comment, as it seems that, for him, when you take the union of some elements, that means the set that contains this elements, which is not the standard use of "union" that I read. As for your professors comments, the elements of $G/H$ are **definitely** subsets of $G$ according to the standard definition I gave in this answer. On the other hand, I do understand what they mean by "don't look at $G/H$'s elements as sets". Indeed, in the case where $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $G/H$ becomes a group for the law:

Comment: $(gH)(g'H)=(gg')H$. So, as you see $G/H$ as a group itself, it usually (not always) doesn't mean anything to care about what the elements of $G/H$ are. All you care about is the algebraic properties. $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\{1,i,-1,-i\}$ are definitely different sets, but the first under addition and the second under multiplication give two isomorphic groups, i.e, their algebraic structure is the **same** despite the difference in elements. Notice that the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ are subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$. It's just that, you forget about that unless you really need it.

Comment: @Scientifica, the question is what you mean by $\{A,B\}$? If $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{3,4\}$ and you mean $\{A,B\}=\{1,2,3,4\}$ then it's one thing. But if you mean $\{A,B\}=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$ then it's a completely different thing. It's not the same set, even not the same cardinality.

Comment: And anyway, getting back to the original question, this is what can be said for sure: the union of the left cosets is $G$, that is true. Because when we say "union of cosets" we think of each coset as a set of elements of $G$. I never said anything different. My point is just that the elements of $G/H$ are the formal cosets and not the elements inside them. If by "union of elements of $G/H$ OP meant union of the left cosets then fine, I didn't understand him right. Still important to note that elements of $G$ are not elements of $G/H$.

Comment: @Mark if $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{3,4\}$ then, certainly, $\{A,B\}=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$. The union of $A$ and $B$ is $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Now, let $S=\{A,B\}$. Q: What are the elements of $S$? A: $A$ and $B$. Q: What is the union of the elements of $S$? A: It is the union of $A$ and $B$. Q: What is the union of $A$ and $B$? A: $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Q: So, what is the union of the elements of $S=\{A,B\}=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$? A: It is $\bigcup S=A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4\}$. (one also says of $\bigcup S$ as "union of $S$").

Comment: @Mark You said "the elements of $G/H$ are the formal cosets". Yes fine, and which are typically the left cosets (left or right, ofc, does'nt matter if $H\trianglelefteq G$). Now you said that you fine with saying "the union of the left cosets is $G$", right? Now: Q: What are the elements of $G/H$? A: The left cosests of $H$. Q: What is the union of the elements of $G/H$? A: The union of the cosets of $H$, which is hence $G$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. OP meant union of the elements as sets. I got confused and thought by "union of elements of $G/H$ he was talking about putting all the elements of $G/H$ into one set. That way we were getting only a set of cosets, not a set of elements of $G$. I got confused because he asked about quotient groups. But actually the union of left cosets is $G$ even if $H$ is not a normal subgroup.

Comment: Yeah it's a matter of terminology.